# Grails plugin transitive dependency causing compilation failure: spring-security-core (Required: 1.2.7.3, Found: 1.2.7.3)

Tags: spring, grails, plugins, spring-security

I have written a plugin which provides some custom setup/functionality around the spring-security-core plugin.

In my plugin, I have a dependency on spring-security-core in the BuildConfig.groovy file. The whole file is as follows:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

grails.project.fork = [
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
inherits("global") {
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
}

plugins {

    compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"

    build(":release:3.0.1",
          ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
        export = false
    }
}
```

}

And I have then packaged my plugin and installed it into another application as follows:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.7
grails.project.source.level = 1.7
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
inherits("global") {
}
log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo id: "uy_repo", url: "https://maven.york.ac.uk/nexus/content/repositories/infodir-thirdparty"
    mavenRepo id: "infodirreleases", url: "https://maven.york.ac.uk/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
}

dependencies {
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.2"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.40.0", "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.40.0"
    runtime 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.1.0'
}

plugins {
    compile ":jetty:2.0.3"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    compile ":mongodb:1.3.1"
    compile ":mail:1.0.4"
    compile ":greenmail:1.3.4"
    compile ":elasticsearch:0.0.2.5"
    compile ":codenarc:0.21"

    compile "org.mycompany:grails-security-pre-authenticated:1.0.0"

    test ":geb:0.9.2"
    compile ":ckeditor:3.6.6.1.1"
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.8" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.1.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.0"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
}
```

}

When I add this plugin dependency, it installs successfully, and I also see the message indicating that spring security core plugin has been successfully installed in the console. However, when I attempt to run and command which requires compilation, such as 'grails war' I see the following error message:

```
Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [securityPreAuthenticated]
- Plugin: securityPreAuthenticated
   - Dependencies:
       - spring-security-core (Required: 1.2.7.3, Found: 1.2.7.3)
```

As you can see, the error is saying 1.2.7.3 is required and that 1.2.7.3 is found. Has anyone seen this before, or could possibly advise?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use `spring-security-core` in your app as well? If you do, then `exclude` the dependency provided by the plugin

Comment: No, we don't. We want the spring security core dependency to be a transitive dependency of our own plugin.

If I added the exclude then it would not be installed in the application at all and cause an error such as:


Dependencies:
       ! spring-security-core (Required: 1.2.7.3, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]

Comment: Can you add BuildConfig from the app? Also check in dependency-report that this dependency is not conflicted.

Comment: I have updated my post to include copies of both my plugin's BuildConfig and the app to which I have installed my plugins. It's the grails-security-preauthenticated dependency in the 2nd BuildConfig which pulls in my custom plugin.

Comment: Have you also tried clean and compile? I would also accompany deleting the dependencies from local repo and let it download again.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @dmahapatro I have a similar issue with Grails and Spring Security. Perhaps you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494260/install-grails-spring-security-ldap-and-spring-security-core-plugin-configuratio